How to install DaVinci Resolve on Ubuntu 24.04
If you try to install DaVinci Resolve 19 using the official installer in Ubuntu 24.04, it complains about missing dependencies. If you force the installation with SKIP_PACKAGE_CHECK=1 it installs but doesn't run.
What is the easiest way to get DaVinci Resolve 19 to install and work on Ubuntu 24.04?

I’ve created an Ansible script that fully automates the installation process on Ubuntu 24.04.
Here’s what the script does:

It does not install older versions of system dependencies, unlike other solutions.
No containerization (like distrorun) is needed.
The script extracts the AppImage files from the official installer and replaces outdated libraries by creating symlinks to the correct versions of the libraries from your Ubuntu 24.04 system.
It takes care of downloading the official installer from the DaVinci Resolve website.
Installs everything in the standard /opt/ directory.
Sets up udev rules for DaVinci Panel and similar USB peripherals.
Installs necessary system icons and MIME files.
Auto-detects your GPU (AMD, Intel, or Nvidia) and installs the appropriate OpenCL libraries.

To get DaVinci Resolve 19 working on Ubuntu 24.04, follow these steps:

Install Git and Make if they aren’t already installed:
sudo apt install git make


Clone the repository:
git clone https://github.com/leinardi/JDInstaller.git


Switch to the repository directory:
cd JDInstaller


Check out the DaVinci Resolve branch (it’s disabled by default in the main script):
git checkout davinci


Run the installation:
make install TAGS=davinci_resolve



This should fully automate the process and get DaVinci Resolve running on Ubuntu 24.04 without the need for manual package downgrades or containers. You can find the full script here:
https://github.com/leinardi/JDInstaller
DaVinci Resolve running on Ubuntu 24.04 on Intel hardware:

DaVinci Resolve running on Ubuntu 24.04 on AMD hardware:


Most people to use this script will have downloaded the official installer and failed to run it, so there shouldn't be a need to download again - or at least there should be an option to use an existing appimage. Also it offers no information on source or download destination for the user to intervene. This is worryingly opaque. Davinci's original installer shouldn't be possible to download like this, since they require filling their form to get the link. That said, the instructions worked well to install the software, so can't complain.

Also, this isn't able to use the graphics card and I wasn't able to make it work and now I don't know how to uninstall (short of deleting the files) either resolve or ansible. Could you please update those instructions as well?

@VidyutGore-Kale I have already given you an answer here: https://github.com/leinardi/JDInstaller/issues/16#issuecomment-2530920256
